# How to monitor executable-jar application installed on cloud foundry

Tags: java, executable, executable-jar, cloud-foundry

In cloud foundry, I have installed an executable jar as application. This application does not have any web url or endpoint. This application is more like my background processor. I would like to monitor whether this application is still running or not? 
Since there is no endpoint, could do some ping test or so.
Kindly suggest me to solve this scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you deployed this app using `cf push --no-route` (or app manifest equivalent).
If you also specify `-u none` (or app manifest equivalent), Cloud Foundry will actually watch its process, so you can use `cf app your-app` to monitor whether it's still running or not.

Comment: A couple other ideas.  You could add a dead man's switch to your app.  Basically have it call out to some service or end point on a predictable frequency.  If the app does not check in on that frequency then you know something is wrong.  You could also use the output of `cf events` which will have crash events if your app does have a problem (assuming the problem results in the app existing and CF restarting your app).  The benefit of this is that the problem doesn't have to be happening at the time you check the service.  You'll see the issues in the event history.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [cf top](https://github.com/ECSTeam/cloudfoundry-top-plugin) plugin.

It is the **best plugin** for a platform operator. It provides real time view on what's happening with the foundation, a Diego cell, or an LRP.

If you have `admin` privileges, you off course can see a lot of details. Without `admin` privileges, the plugin restricts to monitoring up-to 100 LRPs.

And, I use it extensively on a daily basis.